# What is the win32/system call equivalent of getting the scan code from keyboard?

Tags: windows, tasm

i have this code in tasm

```
mov ah,00h
int 21h

cmp ah,3Bh
```

it works pretty well considering it is a dos based appication (we can see that it uses interrupts which are fairly old). Now the questions is, what is the win32/system call equivalent of getting the scan code from keyboard? Basically, when a user presses the F1 key (scan code is 3Bh), it gets registered in the AH register. How can we implement this in win32 assembly via system calls? (the one with extrn, kernel32 dlls , etc)
Im using NASM

Comment: http://uhost.rmutp.ac.th/wanapun.w/sys-tc/ch2-1.pdf

Comment: This is my current implementation. Im asking about how to implement this in win32 using system / function calls

Comment: Ah, I see. You can confuse all of us less if you include what you are actually asking for in the title of your question. :)

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919413/how-to-get-the-key-state-via-a-scancode-not-virtual-keycode

Answer (score 1):

For a console mode program, the likeliest home for 32-bit assembly code, it is [ReadConsoleInput()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  A GUI app gets keystrokes from the WM_KEYDOWN and the WM_CHAR messages, returned by GetMessage().  But of course you'd never write a GUI app in assembly, there's just no point to that.

Calling _getch() from the C runtime library is probably the easiest way to do this, it is a simple function that returns an int.